What factors to include in salary negotiations moving from employee to contractor status?
I am UK based developer with a smallish UK employer (aprx 100 employees).
For various reasons I am having to move abroad. However, my employer can only employ UK residents directly, so to accommodate this move, they are allowing me to transition from direct employee to a contractor. This is not the norm for them, and it is taking work on their behalf to set up, so I genuinely do appreciate their flexibility.
But... salary....
My current salary is pretty much market rate for my role.
I had expected to move onto a contractor rate that was also standard for this role. That rate is 2 x the equivalent salaried rate.
However, when talking to my employer's representative, she proposed to calculate my day rate based on current salary + pension contributions + social security payments (i.e. payments I will have to make as a contractor, that they previously made as a direct employer). But that is significantly less than the average contractor rate (about 1.5 x salary rate, compared to 2 x salary rate).
I would like to negotiate the contractor rate up to the average: 2 x equivalent salary. This seems reasonable to me. And there must be reasons for the average contractor rate being what it is.
As well as the hard payments like social security and pension, I think there are further benefits to the employer when contracting - no obligation/liabilities for the future, no sick pay, no equipment usage, and probably more that I can't think of.
Despite being happy with my current role, and being pleased with my employer in general I also want to get a fair rate, and yes, the best deal I can for myself. I feel like this is the time to negotiate a decent salary, because it will be the baseline for future increases / negotiations. However I'm aware that my role in negotiations is weaker than theirs, because essentially they are doing me a favour by going to the time and expense of setting this up for me.
What can I do to negotiate my contractor rate upwards, and what factors might I reasonably take into account when it comes to calculating my expected contractor rate from my current employee salary?
Edit to add:
The destination country has roughly the same cost of living as the UK, but from my employer's POV I'm not sure this is relevant. Wherever I live, I would like to negotiate the best contractor salary I can. My query is how to justify the higher rate of 2 x salary, which is the average rate for contractors in my field.

x1.5 sounds like a bad deal depending on taxes, energy-costs, and other fees of your future destination. Just as a additional bargaining chip for a higher rate than 'current salary + pension contributions + social security payments' you could argue that as a remote contractor you have to pay for your own office, electricity, mobile, pc, inet etc. etc. and that would reduce costs and free up resources on their side.

Where are you moving to and what is cost of living vs UK? This will influence how hard you need to push here. E.g. If your flat in the new country costs half of what it does in London, maybe 1.5x your current salary is not too bad. I.e. Don't compare to UK contractor rates, compare to contractor rates in your new country. Now if it's similar cost of living then disregard this

Thanks for your comments. The cost of living is actually very similar in the destination country, but I'm not sure location is really relevant to my question - or at least to my employer (if I went to live in Hong Kong or, conversely, Nigeria, it wouldn't make a difference to them). I'm more concerned with getting a preferential contractor rate, wherever I reside.

“no sick pay, no equipment usage, and probably more that I can't think of.” - You can negotiate time off, but you also have the benefit of working whenever you want, provided you get your work done. Likewise, you can negotiate that they send you hardware, that you will return of course if you break the contract or it’s not renewed. You might want to be careful, UK and other countries have very specific policies, when determining what is a contractor position and what’s an employee (company) position. Your requests might make it impossible for them to hire you.

What does your accountant say? Ask them. Also, if your employer is telling you when to work and how long for, you (and they) may run into IR35 regulations; again, ask your accountant.

Does the UK have any pesky laws that say a contractor after a certain period of time of fulltime work is then considered an employee? The US has laws like this. This can impede long-term work. Also, local cost of living matters very much. There is a reason companies hire contractors in India versus US (California).

Related - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101913/what-are-some-of-the-legal-consequences-of-hiring-full-time-employees-as-indepen

Tools is a big part of this. If you are to provide all PC infrastructure as well as software licenses, that costs a lot of money. To the point where contracts often contains a special clause about who pays for tools/licenses.

I think the issue you need to clarify is whether they're doing you a favour making a special arrangement for someone they essentially view as an employee and want to retain, or whether they see any financial advantage themselves to the different legal arrangements.
All your arguments are sound that a genuine contractor working for an employer who had sought out a contractor in the first place, would expect to be paid more per day.
But you're not a genuine contractor - you're an employee who has asked for a concession to be made.
I'd be very careful about looking the gift horse in the mouth, having asked for special arrangements and received them, and then asking for another 50% salary in your pocket on top (which is a whopping increase).

Exactly this. While they do also use contractors (and therefore I presume they are familiar with going rates), they were happy to keep me as an direct employee, so the contractor move is to benefit me, not them.  Nevertheless, they will look to save money on the move if possible - which is fine, but I don't want it to be at my expense :)   So I am looking for advice on the arguments I could make during (friendly) negotiations when the topic turns to $$.

I concur. The OP has asked for, and has received, special dispensation. I'd think twice about looking this gift horse in the mouth as well.

@MartinHansenLennox, it's unclear how familiar your employer is with contractors, and whether or not there is an accepted multiplier or formula to translate between a salary and a contractor day rate, and how much of a wrench it has been to indulge you. I think it would be implicit that your take-home would be the same, but once you're getting into the realm of saying that you should get extra for the loss of job security, you're attempting to convert wholly contingent, back-loaded costs into assured, front-loaded costs. (1/3)

It stops being "could you help me out by letting me stay on another few months/years as a contractor while I move abroad?" to "can I trade my future job security for a higher wage now?". Your employer may not have bargained for the latter, especially because your fate will be resignation in the short-term if they do not grant you the concession (i.e. you have no job security and they have no contingent costs associated with your dismissal), and you risk sounding presumptuous and inflammatory if you suggest that such a trade was implicit in your request. (2/3)

You also risk making the negotiation unwantedly complex once you start talking about the future need to signal your status and real economic value as a contractor - when, again, you seem to have presented the situation as a way to continue your employment under different arrangements, not as you making a shift to contracting (where you'd be telling them they either pay you the going rate, or lump it and you'll go elsewhere to someone who will). I would clarify in your own mind what you are seeking, then seek consent for that thing as a whole, rather than renegotiating as you go along. (3/3)

@Carmax it seems that from their perspective, they're looking to pay exactly as much as they used to, not even save any money. But of course normally a contractor has to price "I'm taking all these extra risks" in as well...

Another factor is the transfer of risk from the company to you. Once you are a contractor, you are at risk of sudden termination. You also are assuming the risks of "errors and omissions" for which the company can ask you to pay for.
As an independent contractor, it is advisable to be spending significant amounts of time looking for the next contract. Rates need to be adjusted up to cover times when not having a contract.
Rates need to also cover insurances that you need when being an independent business. E&O insurance may not be much, but it is still an expense. There may be other locally mandated expenses you need to pay to register your business.

Ignoring the cost of living difference when you move abroad, but that will be a consideration.

However, when talking to my employer's representative, she proposed to
calculate my day rate based on current salary + pension contributions

social security payments (i.e. payments I will have to make as a contractor, that they previously made as a direct employer). But that
is significantly less than the average contractor rate (about 1.5 x
salary rate, compared to 2 x salary rate).

As well as the hard payments like social security and pension, I think
there are futher benefits to the employer when contracting - no
obligation/liabilities for the future, no sick pay, no equipment
usage, and probably more that I can't think of.

The biggest items you are missing are the things that most people forget: vacation days, and national holidays. Yes, I used US terms. Those are days that your employer pays you but you didn't do any work. Part of the excess you charge each hour/day you do work, is used to cover those days you don't. If there are 10 national holidays and you normally get 4 weeks vacation that is 6 weeks of missing work hours you need to factor in.

Your annual bill before VAT should be close to twice your gross income. That means you take your annual income with no taxes, no pension, nothing deducted and multiply by a factor close to two. 1.5 would be low. You divide this number by 230 to get a daily rate.
For this premium the employee has the advantage of not paying a penny when you are sick, having someone who will gladly cover bank holidays because bank holidays don’t get paid, and the save 15% employers national insurance. In addition you have no protection for unemployment so your contract can be cancelled instantly big they don’t need you.
You have the advantage that you can arrange your income. You can pay 12,000 income a year, very little in national insurance, then pay corporation tax and fill your income up to 50,270 using dividends at 8%. You can pay in a pension fund tax free (highly recommended below 40), or leave money in the company (recommended if you ar over 50 to pay for early retirement, all highly tax efficient).
But these peoples numbers, basically paying your gross salary, that’s ridiculous. They basically make money at your expense.

Misclassifying employees as independent contractors has some very real legal and tax implications. Your employer risks the wrath of the tax councils if your work continues as normal and they change your classification from employee to independent contractor. They (the government) are probably also not going to take too kindly to your employer using the employee/contractor distinction to game the immigration policy.
Do you work as a sole proprietorship or have you started your own business that will quote for the work you have done? That is one of the ways to prove you are an independent contractor.
Is the work you are going to do temporary? A project set for a certain time or some sort of event that would bring the temporary employment to an end? Independant Contracts are generally not long-term. If they want you to work on indefinitely then that makes you an employee.
Either way, you and your employer are playing with fire. You should not be surprised when you get a nasty burn from the tax authorities
